# Proper Syntax for List Comprehension Involving an Integer and a Float?

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension

I have a List of Lists that looks like this (Python3):

```
myLOL = ["['1466279297', '703.0']", "['1466279287', '702.0']", "['1466279278', '702.0']", "['1466279268', '706.0']", "['1466279258', '713.0']"]
```

I'm trying to use a list comprehension to convert the first item of each inner list to an int and the second item to a float so that I end up with this:

```
newLOL = [[1466279297, 703.0], [1466279287, 702.0], [1466279278, 702.0], [1466279268, 706.0], [1466279258, 713.0]]
```

I'm learning list comprehensions, can somebody please help me with this syntax?

Thank you!

[edit - to explain why I asked this question]

This question is a means to an end - the syntax requested is needed for testing. I'm collecting sensor data on a ZigBee network, and I'm using an Arduino to format the sensor messages in JSON. These messages are published to an MQTT broker (Mosquitto) running on a Raspberry Pi. A Redis server (also running on the Pi) serves as an in-memory message store. I'm writing a service (python-MQTT client) to parse the JSON and send a LoL (a sample of the data you see in my question) to Redis. Finally, I have a dashboard running on Apache on the Pi. The dashboard utilizes Highcharts to plot the sensor data dynamically (via a web socket connection between the MQTT broker and the browser). Upon loading the page, I pull historical chart data from my Redis LoL to "very quickly" populate the charts on my dashboard (before any realtime data is added dynamically). I realize I can probably format the sensor data the way I want in the Redis store, but that is a problem I haven't worked out yet. Right now, I'm trying to get my historical data to plot correctly in Highcharts. With the data properly formatted, I can get this piece working.

Comment: This is a bit of a strange format. Where did it come from? Did you write a bunch of lists out to disk in `repr` format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could use [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
from ast import literal_eval

myLOL = ["['1466279297', '703.0']", "['1466279287', '702.0']", "['1466279278', '702.0']", "['1466279268', '706.0']", "['1466279258', '713.0']"]

items = [[int(literal_eval(i)[0]), float(literal_eval(i)[1])] for i in myLOL]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import json
newLOL = [[int(a[0]), float(a[1])] for a in (json.loads(s.replace("'", '"')) for s in myLOL)]
```

Here I'm considering each element of the list as a JSON, but since it's using `'` instead of `"` for the strings, I have to replace it first (it only works because you said there will be only numbers).

Answer (score 0):

This may work? I wish I was more clever.

```
newLOL = [] 
for listObj in myLOL:
    listObj = listObj.replace('[', '').replace(']', '').replace("'", '').split(',')
    newListObj = [int(listObj[0]), float(listObj[1])]
    newLOL.append(newListObj)
```

Iterates through your current list, peels the string apart into a list by replace un-wanted string chracters and utilizing a split on the comma. Then we take the modified list object and create another new list object with the values being the respective ints and floats. We then append the prepared newListObj to the newLOL list. Considering you want an actual set of lists within your list. Your previously documented input list actually contains strings, which look like lists.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very strange format and the best solution is likely to change the code which generates that.

That being said, you can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to **safely** evaluate the elements of the list as Python tokens:

```
>>> lit = ast.literal_eval
>>> [[lit(str_val) for str_val in lit(str_list)] for str_list in myLOL]
[[1466279297, 703.0], [1466279287, 702.0], [1466279278, 702.0], [1466279268, 706.0], [1466279258, 713.0]]
```

We need to do it twice - once to turn the string into a list containing two strings, and then once per resulting string to convert it into a number.

Note that this will succeed even if the strings contain other valid tokens. If you want to validate the format too, you'd want to do something like:

```
>>> def process_str_list(str_list):
...     l = ast.literal_eval(str_list)
...     if not isinstance(l, list):
...         raise TypeError("Expected list")
...     str_int, str_float = l
...     return [int(str_int), float(str_float)]
...
>>> [process_str_list(str_list) for str_list in myLOL]
[[1466279297, 703.0], [1466279287, 702.0], [1466279278, 702.0], [1466279268, 706.0], [1466279258, 713.0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input consists of a list of strings, where each string is the string representation of a list. The first task is to convert the strings back into lists:

```
import ast
lol2 = map(ast.literal_eval, mylol) # [['1466279297', '703.0'], ...]
```

Now, you can simply get `int` and `float` values from `lol2`:

```
newlol = [[int(a[0]), float(a[1])] for a in lol2]
```